# Writing five other iterated integrals that are equal to the given iterated integral

Tags: multivariable-calculus

The given integral is $$\int_{0}^{1}\int_{0}^{x^2}\int_{0}^{y} f(x,y,z) dz dy dx$$

I'm looking at the solution and I understand how to switch the order so that I have $dz dx dy$

The full solution:

[image]
[image]

[image]

I'm mainly confused on how to set up the graphs for (2)-(5). I understand how to do (1) but I'm unsure how to set up the integrals for the remaining combinations

Comment: The first picture is for a *fixed* value of $y$.

Comment: @user1046533 Hi, I just updated with the full solution

Comment: Thanks for that. Maybe you could organize your questions and refer to the labels (1),(2),(3),(4),(5).

Comment: It seems that you already understand (1) and you are asking (2)-(5). Instead of asking them all at the same time, maybe one step at a time; people may write answers more conveniently if you have a shorter one.

Comment: yes, (2)-(5) is what I'm confused about

Comment: It is a bit difficult to scroll up and down to write an answer. For example, it would be a lot easier, if you start with (1) and ask how to get (2). // Basically, work with the outer pair or the inner pair each time.

Comment: got it, thank you. I will edit my question so that it is more readable

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The main idea is to reduce the problem to a *double integral* problem. There are two parts.

**Part I.** The inner pair.

Let us begin with something you understand already:
$$
\int_{0}^{1} \int_{\sqrt{y}}^{1} \int_{0}^{y} f(x, y, z)\; d z d x d y\tag{1}
$$

So you want to switch the order in the "inner pair" to get $dxdzdy$ as in (2). First, write (1) as
$$
\int_{0}^{1}\left( \int_{\sqrt{y}}^{1} \int_{0}^{y} f(x, y, z)\; d z d x \right)d y\tag{1a}
$$

Note that for each **fixed** value of $y\in[0,1]$, the inner part is a double integral
$$
\int_{\sqrt{y}}^{1} \int_{0}^{y} f(x, y, z)\; d z d x\tag{1b}
$$
This is a double integral on the $zx$-plane where the region that you integrate on is a *rectangle*, $[0,y]\times[\sqrt{y},1]$. Again remember that $y$ is a fixed number here (which means you should think it as a constant). So (1b) is equal to (by the Fubini theorem)
$$
\int_{\sqrt{y}}^{1} \int_{0}^{y} f(x, y, z)\; d z d x= \int_{0}^{y} \int_{\sqrt{y}}^{1} f(x, y, z)\; d x d z\tag{1c}
$$
Combining (1c) and (1a) you get (2):
$$
\int_{0}^{1}  \int_{0}^{y}\int_{\sqrt{y}}^{1} f(x, y, z)\; d x d z d y\tag{2}
$$

**Part II.** The outer pair.

Now you want to switch the order in the "out pair" to get $dxdydz$. Rewrite (2) as
$$
\int_{0}^{1} \int_{0}^{y} \left(\int_{\sqrt{y}}^{1} f(x, y, z)\; d x\right) d z d y\tag{2a}
$$
Note that after integrating with respect to $x$, the inner part is a function in $z$ and $y$. Let us write it as $g(z,y):=\left(\int_{\sqrt{y}}^{1} f(x, y, z)\; d x\right)$ so (2a) is
$$
\int_{0}^{1} \int_{0}^{y} g(z,y) d z d y\tag{2a}
$$
which is nothing but a double integral on the $zy$-plane now! Now you use the diagram below the formula (2) in your solution to switch the order
$$
\int_{0}^{1} \int_{0}^{y} g(z,y) d z d y=\int_{0}^{1} \int_{z}^{1} g(z,y) d y d z\tag{2c}
$$
Combining (2a)-(2c) you get (3):
$$
\int_{0}^{1} \int_{z}^{1} \int_{\sqrt{y}}^{1} f(x, y, z) d x d y d z
\tag{3}
$$

You can now proceed similarly to get (4) and then (5).